# Is Image Magick 6.2.4 always backwardly compatible with legacy versions?

Tags: php, imagemagick, backwards-compatibility

## To use the PHP extension for ImageMagick, I need to upgrade my server to ImageMagick version 6.2.4.

[image]
<sub>(source: [gsp.com](http://gsp.com/support/vps/basic/admin/ports/ports/ImageMagick/magick.png))</sub>

However I have some legacy code that uses version **6.0.7**

I saw a slashdot comment from **2006** about ImageMagick being [notoriously bad for backwards compatibility](http://books.slashdot.org/books/06/03/13/1442239.shtml#comment_top_14913297) but I have no personal experience of this. Looking throught the archives it seems as though my current versionis from **circa 2005**.

**Does anyone know if ImageMagick is now stable enough to upgrade without too much difficulty?**

Comment: IM's backwards compatibility isn't great, that is my (limited) experience too. What functions does your code use exactly?  The less fancy, the more likely it is that it will work

Answer (score 0):

See this [compatibility table](http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/versions/imagemagick.html) for the ImageMagick C/C++ API:

[image]